# Get selected radio button from dynamically generated set in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, radio-button

I'm working with ASP.NET (2.0), and we want to generate a group of radio buttons from a data source.  This is simple enough using RadioButtonList, but we want the text associated with each radio button to have more formatting...in particular, some of the text should be regular weight, some bold.  This doesn't seem like a good match for RadioButtonList.

Using a Repeater, I can easily create a single RadioButton for each item in the DataSet, give them the same GroupName, and they'll work correctly on the client side...but then when the form is submitted, it's not clear to me how to discover what button was selected (server side).  Unlike RadioButtonList, I don't have a single containing object that I can ask for the selected item from.

We could also use something a bit more interactive, by posting information back to the server on a radio button click, but we'd like to avoid extra postbacks if possible.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

Put your RadioButton's in panel, then iterate control collection of Panel

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType().Name == "RadioButton")
        {
            if (((RadioButton)ctrl).Checked)
            {
                //...Do your Stuff..
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting this up, because it will definitely work, and it may be the way I have to go...but I'd hate this to be the only solution.  I was hoping for something more elegant (which is a complaint about the ability of the framework...not your answer!)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a repeater, then you can use the ItemCommand event.  More here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx

Comment: Somethign like this might work in some situations, but we'd like the user to be able to select an item, and do some other work before submitting the form, while this solution causes a submit.  Also, as near as I can tell, the itemCommand event is associated with Buttons, but not RadioButtons, so it won't work in this case.

Comment: the itemcommand is not associated only with buttons...  Anyway, if you want to avoid post-backs, you should ammend your question, because the itemcommand is the 'normal' way to handle this otherwise.  I put up another answer that avoids post-backs.

Comment: alternatively, if you can live with very limited post-backs, you can just wrap your radiobuttons in update panels ajax style.

Comment: Good point...I modified the question to mention that sending information back to the server on each click isn't ideal for this scenario.  Also, while i'm not seeing how ItemCommand would work with RadioButtons (compared with just buttons), you're probably right...I'm probably just missing it.

Comment: No -- you are right -- I didn't realize it wouldn't fire for radiobuttons -- my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Basically like @Muhammad's answer -- but using the repeater instead of a panel.  Just call this sub whenever you submit the form.

```
Private Sub rep()
    Dim myRepeater As New Repeater
    Dim myRadio As New RadioButton
    For Each myItem As RepeaterItem In myRepeater.Items
        myRadio = CType(myItem.FindControl("radio1"), RadioButton)
        If myRadio.Checked Then
            'do something
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```